# Can't access GET Parameter

Tags: php, .htaccess

I use the Tonic Framework (https://github.com/peej/tonic) for my rest-webservice.

GetUser:

```
    /**
    * This class defines an example resource that is wired into the URI /example (/{id})?
    * @namespace Test
    * @uri /nff/user/{uid}
    */
    require_once('dbmodel.php');
    require_once('error.php');
    require_once('user.php');
    class GetUserController extends Resource {


        function get($request,$uid) {
       .....
}
```

My Problem is that i can't access the `$_GET` parameter.

I think the problem could be in the `.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    #exclude
    RewriteRule ^img/ - [L]
    RewriteRule ^verify.php - [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !dispatch\.php$  
    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule .* dispatch.php [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Please help

Comment: What happens when you try to access `$_GET`?

Comment: to a print_r($_GET) first to see if anything is in there, and work from there.

Comment: $_GET: Array
(
    [dispatch_php] => 
    [redirect:/dispatch_php/30] => 
    [nff/user_php/30] => 
)

Answer (score 1):

Your last rewrite rule rewrites everything to dispatch.php without the attached GET parameters. You have to add a rule with the parameters and rewrite to dispatch.php?$1

```
RewriteRule ^[^\?]*\?(.*)$ dispatch.php?$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule .* dispatch.php [L,QSA]
```

Comment: i copied it, but when i call my webservice and print_r($_GET) the parameter isn't passed

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the escape character for the `?`

Comment: now i have: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
 
 #exclude
 RewriteRule ^img/ - [L]
 RewriteRule ^verify.php - [L]
 
    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !dispatch\.php$ 
 RewriteRule ^[^\?]*\?(.*)$ dispatch.php?$1 [L,QSA]
    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule .* dispatch.php [L,QSA]
</IfModule>

and it doesn't work